# Check if $W$ is a subspace of $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ and if it is, represent it as a linear span if possible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W=\left\{        \begin{bmatrix}
        \alpha+\beta & \beta+\gamma & \gamma+\delta \\
        \beta+\gamma & \alpha+\beta & \beta+\gamma \\
        \gamma+\delta & \beta+\gamma & \alpha+\beta \\
        \end{bmatrix}:\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb R\right\}$. Check if $W$ is a subspace of $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ and if it is, represent it as a linear span if possible.

What is the procedure for checking if $W$ is a subspace of $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$?

How can we check if $W$ can be represented as a linear span?

How to represent a set $W$ as a linear span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $W=\left\{        \begin{bmatrix}
        \alpha+\beta & \beta+\gamma & \gamma+\delta \\
        \beta+\gamma & \alpha+\beta & \beta+\gamma \\
        \gamma+\delta & \beta+\gamma & \alpha+\beta \\
        \end{bmatrix}:\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb R\right\}$. 
The generic matrix in this set is equal to
 $     \begin{bmatrix}
        \alpha+\beta & 0 & 0\\
        0 & \alpha+\beta & 0 \\
        0& 0& \alpha+\beta\\
       \end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
        0 &\beta +\gamma & 0\\
        \beta + \gamma & 0 & \beta+\gamma \\
        0& \beta+\gamma & 0\\
       \end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & \gamma+\delta\\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \gamma+\delta & 0& 0\\
       \end{bmatrix}$.

So $W $ can be written as a span of three matrices (as given, substitute each of non zero entries with 1 for example), hence a subspace.

Comment: What is the procedure to determine a subspace $U$ such that $W\oplus U=M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: You need to find vectors from $\ M_{2x2} \  so \ U\cap W=0$

Comment: And the span of vectors from $W $ and $U $ combined, is equal to the space of 3×3 matrices.

Comment: The easiest way to do so is to add  canonic vectors that are linearly independent with vectors from the basis of $\ W$

Comment: @CTSnake, Could you show the procedure?

Comment: Thats a lot of work in your case, because I suppose you've got dimW=4 because the dimM is 9 you have to find 5 matrices that are linear independent with matrices from W.

Comment: @CTSnake, Could you show it on an example of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ space?

Comment: Lets say we have $\ B_w={\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}.\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}} dimW=2$ because we need to generate the whole $\ M_{2x2} $ and because $\ dimM_{2x2}=4 $we need to find two vectors that are lineary independent with vectors from$\ B_w $ we see that $\ \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$ are LI with vectors from $\ B_w$  we conclude that $\ B_{W+U}=\{ \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1},\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}.\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}\}$

Comment: @CTSnake, How can we choose a canonical basis for $W$?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: @CTSnake, Because in your example, $B_{w}$ is a basis for $W$, right ($M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$)?

Comment: yes for W,  you don't have to find canonical vectors for W

Comment: @CTSnake, For finding $U$ such that $W\oplus U=M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$, two conditions must be satisfied: $1) W+U=M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$, $2) W\cap U=\{0\}$. Could you  explain how did you choose a basis $B_w$? From your $B_{W+U}$, does it follows that $W+U=M_{2\times 2}$ (first statement)? How to check second statement?

Comment: It would be maybe easyer to explain on your mother tounge

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example:
$\ \pmatrix{a+b&a\\b&a+b}=\pmatrix{a&a\\0&a}+\pmatrix{b&0\\b&b}=a\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}+b\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}$

now we have the "template" for all vectors from W and we see that this is $\operatorname{span}(\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1},\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1})$ span is vector subspace by the theorem